# Hunting down qpaeq graphic equalizer preset files

Tags: pulseaudio, filesystem

I'm using pulseEQ on Ubuntu 20.04. I get qpaeq up and running and the GUI isn't great. I have sliders with no axis values. I download my equalizer preset from github/autoEQ, but there's no good way for me to import it. I could do it manually, but even then I can't see what gain value the slider is making, there's no sense of scale at all.

I was hoping, then, that when I save a preset, it would make a file in plain text, which I could then open and enter my preset that way. But I haven't been able to find it.

I look for qpaeq files nearby to the binary:

```
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ which qpaeq
/usr/bin/qpaeq
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /usr/share | grep qpaeq
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /usr/* | grep qpaeq
qpaeq
```

The only thing with the name qpaeq in it in /usr is the binary itself. I don't think there are any related files then in /usr

Any clues in /etc ?

```
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc | grep qpaeq
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc | grep pulseaudio
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc | grep pulse
pulse
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc/pulse
client.conf  client.conf.d  daemon.conf  default.pa  system.pa
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls /etc/pulse/client.conf.d
01-enable-autospawn.conf
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ cat /etc/pulse/client.conf.d/01-enable-autospawn.conf 
cat: /etc/pulse/client.conf.d/01-enable-autospawn.conf: No such file or directory
```

Looking through the .conf and .pa files, they look like they came with the package and like nothing special.

So I created a preset with a unique name and then went to root and did

```
simon@simon-MacBookPro:/$ sudo find . -name presetFindMe
find: ‘./run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/68262/task/68262/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘./proc/68262/net’: Invalid argument
```

and it came up empty.

I found the pid of qpaeq and then looked at it's open files in /proc, and this is what I get:

```
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls -l /proc/54513/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 10 -> 'socket:[111940]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 11 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lr-x------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 12 -> anon_inode:inotify
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 13 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 14 -> 'socket:[110903]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 15 -> 'socket:[114117]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 16 -> 'socket:[110904]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 17 -> 'socket:[110905]'
lr-x------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 18 -> /usr/share/icons/Yaru/icon-theme.cache
lr-x------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 19 -> /usr/share/icons/Humanity/icon-theme.cache
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 20 -> /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/icon-theme.cache
lr-x------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 21 -> /usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 22 -> 'socket:[110906]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 23 -> 'socket:[110907]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 24 -> /dev/dri/card0
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 25 -> /dev/dri/card0
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 26 -> /dev/dri/card0
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 27 -> /dev/dri/card0
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 3 -> 'socket:[111937]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 4 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 5 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 6 -> 'socket:[111939]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 7 -> 'socket:[110902]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 8 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 simon simon 64 Dec  2 11:10 9 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
```

Not promising.

Maybe if I look into pulse itself:

```
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ps aux | grep pulse
simon       1830  4.0  0.2 4333464 35376 ?       S<sl 09:39   6:23 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
root       52858  0.0  0.1 505992 17176 ?        S<l  11:05   0:00 pulseaudio --start
simon      96051  0.0  0.0   9040  2692 pts/5    S+   12:16   0:00 grep --color=auto pulse
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls -l /proc/4333464/fd
ls: cannot access '/proc/4333464/fd': No such file or directory
simon@simon-MacBookPro:~$ ls -l /proc/505992/fd
ls: cannot access '/proc/505992/fd': No such file or directory
```

I'm relatively new to linux. Am I even on the right track? Am I SOL? Would I be better off looking into the source code?

Comment: I think the settings would  more likely be in `~/.config` instead of `/etc` as `/etc` requires root privileges to write to a file and most user configurations are under `~/.config`

Answer (score 0):

It was in ~/.config. Thanks, mchid!

Comment: Ask Ubuntu's purpose is to provide the largest library of questions and answers about Ubuntu for the community, by the community.  It's encouraged to ask and answer your own question, however this answer does not really help anyone else who would visit seeking an answer to the same question.  Please edit your question to provide details explaining exactly how you solved your problem in a way that someone else with your problem would be able to reproduce your solution on their end.  Thanks in advance for your contribution!

Comment: Question: Where are the files?
Answer: They're in ~/.config.
What more is there?

Comment: There's hundreds if not thousands of files in `~/.config`. This is marginally better than saying that the files are somewhere on your hard drive. That wouldn't help anyone, and similarly, this answer probably isn't specific enough to help future visitors.  You should edit your answer so that it is more specific/detailed.  In this case, it's warranted to give the whole path including file names.

Answer (score 0):

The files are in `.config/pulse/`

(OS Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS pulseaudio 15.99.1)

They are in some binary "tbd" format so you cannot edit them with a text editor directly, but can backup and restore them at least.